# aggregate of <aggregation>_over_time() in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

Prometheus has functions to e.g. get the max of a given range of data points or min or ... See the [documentation for more info](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#aggregation-_over_time).

Now when I want min(data) and max(data) and avg, ... I need to send separate requests. How can I achieve this in one query?

[ update ]

From Brian's reply I see that my question is not clear (enough), so let me rephrase:

I have a timeseries "temperature" for a day in 15sec intervals.
And I want for each hour (or last hour, doesn't really matter) have
min/max/avg/stddev, ...

with the `*_over_time()` functions I need to send a query for each of min/max/avg/... (and the correct time interval). Is there a way of doing so in one single query (so basically returning a hash with k-v-pairs containing min/max/avg/...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min(min_over_time(metric[1h]))` will let you do this.

[update]

It's best to send one query per function you want to calculate. You could do it in one with trickery, but it'd be much more complicated and hard to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Looks like my question was not clear enough. I tried to rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to perform multiple PromQL queries in a single query with the help of [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function and [`or` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators). The `label_replace` function is used for giving different names for every `*_over_time()` results, while `or` operator is used for combining multiple `*_over_time()` results into a single response.

For example, the following query returns `min`, `max` and `avg` values for the `temperature` time series over the last hour:

```
label_replace(min_over_time(temperature[1h]), "__name__", "min", "", ".*")
  or
label_replace(max_over_time(temperature[1h]), "__name__", "max", "", ".*")
  or
label_replace(avg_over_time(temperature[1h]), "__name__", "avg", "", ".*")
```

P.S. This query can be simplified into a smaller [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query via [rollup](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup) function:

```
rollup(temperature[1h])
```

If other than `min`, `max` and `avg` results must be calculated, then [aggr_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggr_over_time) function may be used. For example, the following query calculates `median`, `min` and `max` for `temperature` over the last hour:

```
aggr_over_time(
  ("median_over_time", "min_over_time", "max_over_time"), 
  temperature[1h]
)
```

Additionally, MetricsQL provides [alias](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#alias) and [label_set](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_set) functions, which may be easier to use than `label_replace()` when a name or a label must be set to a particular value. For example, the following MetricsQL query is equivalent to the PromQL query above:

```
alias(min_over_time(temperature[1h]), "min")
  or
alias(max_over_time(temperature[1h]), "max")
  or
alias(avg_over_time(temperature[1h]), "avg")
```

MetricsQL also supports [union](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#union) function, which may be used instead of `or` operator when multiple query results must be united into a single response:

```
union(
  alias(min_over_time(temperature[1h]), "min"),
  alias(max_over_time(temperature[1h]), "max"),
  alias(avg_over_time(temperature[1h]), "avg"),
)
```